# Login with query builder

Tags: laravel, query-builder

How can I check the user exists in laravel with this queryBuilder?
the problem is checking password:

```
 $user = DB::table('users')
        ->where('email',$request->input('email'))
        ->where('password',bcrypt($request->input('password')))
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the email

```
$user = DB::table('users')
    ->where('email',$request->input('email'))
    ->first();
```

check the password

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    if(Hash::check($user->password,Hash::make($request->input('password')))){   echo"Password current"; }else{ echo "Password Wrong";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`auth()->attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users):

```
auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])
```

If you want to just check password, use [`Hash::check()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing#basic-usage):

```
Hash::check($request->password, $passwordFromDb)
```